# how to retrieve parameter id parameters in htacess?

Tags: .htaccess

how to take url ID using htacess

where is my url as follows

```
http://localhost/merek.html
```

I want to take string = merek

```
http://localhost/merek/coba-phones-100.html
```

I want to take ID = 100

```
http://localhost/merek/coba-phones-100/coba-6150-125.html
```

I want to take ID = 100 and 125

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?q=$1&idbrand=$2&idmodel=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?q=$1&idbrand=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Fine. Sounds like a great plan. And your question here is _what_ ?

Comment: @arkascha so what if i use pagging
from
http: //localhost/merek/try-phones-100.html
to
http: // localhost / brand / try-phones-100 / page / 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague, since you do not say what the actual issue is.

But I *guess* or *assume* that this is what you are actually asking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ -[END]

RewriteRule ^/?merek/coba-phones-(\d+)/coba-6150-(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?q=merek&idbrand=$1&idmodel=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?merek/coba-phones-(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?q=merek&idbrand=$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?merek\.html$ /index.php?q=merek [END]
```

That would be a more general approach:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ -[END]

RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/.+-(\d+)/.+-(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1&idbrand=$2&idmodel=$3 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/.+-(\d+)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1&idbrand=$2 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)\.html$ /index.php?q=$1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).